Ubuntu 24 reboots several times a day
Recently upgraded Ubuntu 22 to 24. On ubuntu 22 I had a similar issue with random reboots but it was not so often (once a weak) as it happens on ubuntu 24 (several times a day). What can be a reason of such behaviour?
grep 'Automatic-Reboot' /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
            "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot", False):
            "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers", True):
        "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time", "now")

last -x | head | tac
dan      :0           :0               Wed Oct  2 12:42 - crash  (00:53)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.8.0-45-generic Wed Oct  2 12:42 - 13:36  (00:53)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-45-generic Wed Oct  2 13:35   still running
dan      seat0        login screen     Wed Oct  2 13:35 - crash  (01:09)
dan      :0           :0               Wed Oct  2 13:35 - crash  (01:09)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.8.0-45-generic Wed Oct  2 13:36 - 14:45  (01:09)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-45-generic Wed Oct  2 14:45   still running
dan      seat0        login screen     Wed Oct  2 14:45   still logged in
dan      :0           :0               Wed Oct  2 14:45   still logged in
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.8.0-45-generic Wed Oct  2 14:45   still running

So right before the latest reboot I got these lines in terminal with the last command(above) run: (in 18:38 the reboot happened again)
02 18:37:40 dan-desktop gnome-shell[2365]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this.actor is null
                                                  _syncEnabled@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:145:25
                                                  onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:157:35
                                                  _makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:65:22
                                                  _easeActorProperty/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:232:60
                                                  _destroyWindowDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1607:21
                                                  onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1575:39
                                                  _makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:65:22
                                                  _easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:154:64
                                                  @resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21:20
18:37:48 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1976]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.

Today no Errors occured before reboot:
окт 03 11:21:44 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:21:44 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:22:14 dan-desktop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e4:18:6b:26:66:64:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=30481 DF PROTO=2 
окт 03 11:23:23 dan-desktop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e4:18:6b:26:66:64:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42152 DF PROTO=2 
окт 03 11:23:29 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:23:29 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:24:31 dan-desktop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e4:18:6b:26:66:64:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=55463 DF PROTO=2 
окт 03 11:25:01 dan-desktop CRON[61274]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
окт 03 11:25:01 dan-desktop CRON[61275]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
окт 03 11:25:01 dan-desktop CRON[61274]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
окт 03 11:25:11 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:25:11 dan-desktop rtkit-daemon[1996]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
окт 03 11:25:36 dan-desktop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e4:18:6b:26:66:64:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=63401 DF PROTO=2 

P.S. I don't know which information can help to analyze the problem, so please tell me which command to run and I'll edit the question.
System details:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-10-03 13:16:46

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              ASRock AB350M-HDV
- **Memory:**                                      32,0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   AMD Ryzen™ 5 1600 × 12
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD Radeon™ RX 480 Graphics
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1,5 TB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            P1.30
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               46
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.8.0-45-generic


You can use sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex to see log messages leading up to the previous reboot. By varying the -b -1 parameter, you can see other crashes, see sudo journalctl  --list-boots

@waltinator the first command's result is too big. What should I find there?
and the second one gives me a list of hashes only

You should page through the messages, using the less-like pager, looking for Error and Warning messages, anomalies,  etc. The --list-boots option shows you the number to use with -b to  inspect a particular instance to inspect. You can get details by reading man less journalctl logger.

Posting pictures of truncated messages is suboptimal. We cannot scroll right to the interesting (variable) parts of the messages. Rather, copy and paste the whole text into your Question, and bracket the text with <code> ... </code>.

@waltinator I updated the question. Right before reboot I see only the JS Error this.actor is null.
